# create a function to change format of variables in R

Tags: r, function, data.table, factors

I want to create an robuust function to create the format of some columns in my `data.table` in R. I want this to be as robust as possible, as I will be using it on different datasets, which my present different inconsistencies in data. An example data is below:

The objective of this function is two check two columns in the `data.table`: `group` and `category`. They are originally character. I want to mutate them such that:

The group variable should be a factor and would only consist of levels `A`, `B`, and `U`. Everything else should be `U`.

Analogously the variable `category` should be a be a factor and would only consist of levels `E`, `CH`, and `S`. Any empty cells or `NA` should be `E`. Everything else `NA`.

My original data consist of many tens of thousands  of rows, so I am looking for an appropriate solution for large data, ideally `data.table`

```
rm(iris)
iris
group <-rep(c("a", "b", "C", "x", "A", "b", " ", "b", NA , "c"), times = 15) # A,B,U
category <-rep(c("e", "E", "CH", "Ch", "ch", "S", " ", "b", NA , "c"), times = 15) # E, CH, S
iris <- cbind(iris, group, category) 
iris <- iris[1:25,]
setDT(iris)

levels(iris$group) = list( U = "", F = "F", M = "M", U = "U")
levels(iris$category) = list( E = "", CH = "CH", E = "E", S = "S")
```

I have tried this the following way: 1) specify allowed values, 2) change all the values to capital letter, regardless if they are allowed or not (ideally this would be done with one of the `apply` functions in `data.table` using `.SD`, but i havent figured out how that works yet) 3) replace all the values that are not specified within the `allowed_group` or `allowed category` with `NA`

```
allowed_group <- c("U", "A", "B")
allowed_category <- c("E", "CH", "S")

iris$group <- toupper(iris$group)
iris$category <- toupper(iris$category)

iris[,!(group == allowed_group | category == allowed_category)] <- NA
```

original data:

```
> iris
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species group category
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     a        e
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     b        E
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     C       CH
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     x       Ch
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     A       ch
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa     b        S
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa               
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa     b        b
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa  <NA>     <NA>
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa     c        c
11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa     a        e
12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa     b        E
13          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa     C       CH
14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa     x       Ch
15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa     A       ch
16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa     b        S
17          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4  setosa               
18          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa     b        b
19          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3  setosa  <NA>     <NA>
20          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3  setosa     c        c
21          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2  setosa     a        e
22          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4  setosa     b        E
23          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa     C       CH
24          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5  setosa     x       Ch
25          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa     A       ch
```

desired output:

```
> iris
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species group category
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     A        E
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     B        E
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     C       CH
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     U       CH
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     A       CH
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa     B        S
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa     U        E
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa     B     <NA>
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa     U        E
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa     U     <NA>
11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa     A        E
12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa     B        E
13          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa     C       CH
14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa     U       CH
15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa     A       CH
16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa     B        S
17          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4  setosa     U        E
18          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa     B     <NA>
19          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3  setosa     U        E
20          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3  setosa     U     <NA>
21          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2  setosa     A        E
22          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4  setosa     B        E
23          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa     C       CH
24          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5  setosa     U       CH
25          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa     A       CH
```

Comment: I'm still unclear regarding your objective. You want to recode some levels in "tens of thousand of columns" ? You want to do something else ? Could you be more explicit ?

Comment: @linog i am talking about "tens of thousand of rows" :)

Comment: Sorry I misread ;) Still, I would be happy to have more details to help you. Do you need to recode factor levels ?

Comment: What is the operation, check if a data.frame has these columns and that the are formatted properly and return TRUE/FALSE?

Comment: @linog @sindri_baldur clearly i have not asked the question well, therefore i edited it. I want to replace all the values that are now allowed with NA, assuming that empty values in iris$group belong to `U` and empty value in iris$category belong to `E`. the format (character or factor) does actually not matter, as it can be changed later on easily - correct me if i am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To make conditional replacement, you should use the first dimension. With `data.table` operation `:=` (update by reference), you don't need to reassign values. I assumed the NAs you wanted to put were in `group` and `category`. I don't think using a `factor` variable helps in your reproducible example. However, if your real data exhibit factors, you can convert them to characters before the recoding step.

```r
iris
group <-rep(c("a", "b", "C", "x", "A", "b", " ", "b", NA , "c"), times = 15) # A,B,U
category <-rep(c("e", "E", "CH", "Ch", "ch", "S", " ", "b", NA , "c"), times = 15) # E, CH, S
iris <- cbind(iris, group, category) 
iris <- iris[1:25,]
setDT(iris)

allowed_group <- c("U", "A", "B")
allowed_category <- c("E", "CH", "S")

iris[,c("group","category") := lapply(.SD, toupper),
     .SDcols = c("group","category")]
```

Now the conditional replacements. I use on step by variable, easier to handle than my too complicated first answer :

```r
iris[!(group %in% allowed_group), group := "U"]
iris[!(category %in% allowed_category), category := "E"]
```

which yields:

```r
iris
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species group category
 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     A        E
 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     B        E
 3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     U       CH
 4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     U       CH
 5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     A       CH
 6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa     B        S
 7:          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa     U        E
 8:          5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa     B        E
 9:          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa     U        E
10:          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa     U        E
11:          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa     A        E
12:          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa     B        E
13:          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa     U       CH
14:          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa     U       CH
15:          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa     A       CH
16:          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa     B        S
17:          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4  setosa     U        E
18:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa     B        E
19:          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3  setosa     U        E
20:          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3  setosa     U        E
21:          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2  setosa     A        E
22:          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4  setosa     B        E
23:          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa     U       CH
24:          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5  setosa     U       CH
25:          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa     A       CH
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species group category
```

Comment: i have added an desired output to the question (which i should have added on the beginning for clarification)

Comment: you answer is almost the desired thing, although i am not sure why an extra columns called .SD is created? also `B` is in the category column, which is actually not an "allowed value"

Comment: I think I was trying something too complicated. Does my edit correspond to the solution you were looking for ?

Comment: almost, but not quite. for `group`, if the string is not one of the "allowed values" you get `U`. However in `category` observation n.25 is "c" originally and becomes "CH", despite the fact that "C" is not included in the vector of "allowed values. How is it possible?